# Lambda batching processing behavior

Tags: aws-lambda

Currently I'm considering to use Lambda and SQS and having question about batch.

When lambda process multiple messages in batch, Lambda execute multiple messages in parallel?
I'm wondering if batch size is 10, then 10 messages are being processed at the same time or one by one.

Lambda just triggered with 1 aggregated request and my function should be able to handle this 10 messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When lambda process multiple messages in batch, Lambda execute multiple messages in parallel?

The Lambda function gets all 10 messages in its first parameter.

How you process them inside the function (in parallel, serially, or in random order) is totally up to you.

> I'm wondering if batch size is 10, then 10 messages are being processed at the same time or one by one.

Before your function gets invoked, all the messages from the batch become hidden, i.e. other processors reading the same queue won't get (or, rather, unlikely to get) these messages.

As soon as the function completes successfully, all the messages in its batch get deleted from the queue at once.

Alternatively, you can [set up your source mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-eventsource) to report individual failures. In this case, your Lambda function should return a response in [well-defined format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#services-sqs-batchfailurereporting), telling the Lambda runtime which messages succeded, and which failed. Only the successfully processed messages will get deleted from the queue, and the failed ones will return to the queue with the receive counter incremented by one.

Yet another thing you can do is explicitly delete the messages from the queue as soon as they are processed, before waiting for the invocation to complete. It might make sense if your processing logic takes long to complete, or uses shared state which is expensive to prepare. In the former case I would ditch batching altogether; in the latter, I would carefully consider the choice of technology, because Lambda is not a good fit for workflows with expensive shared state.

This pattern could save you money if your lambda function is passing the messages to upstream services and just sitting there waiting for them to complete. With Lambda, you're paying for the clock time your function is running, and it's cheaper if one invocation is waiting for ten upsteam responses. But then again, in this case a cheap EKS pod or a docker container running continously would probably be more cost-efficient.

If your function throws an exception, all the messages are returned to the queue with the receive counter incremented by one (or get sent to the DLQ if the receive counter exceeds the queue retry threshold)

> Lambda just triggered with 1 aggregated request and my function should be able to handle this 10 messages?

Yes, that's exactly how it works.

To the Lambda runtime, your function is a black box. It passes the messages and waits for the function to complete, fail, or return the partial results. What happens inside the function, is totally up to the implementer.

Note that even if you don't enable batching in your source mapping, the messages will still get passed [in an array](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#example-standard-queue-message-event), only that this array will always be exactly one element long. It makes sense to develop your function in such a way that it's always able to process multiple records within a single invocation.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks!